# Inserting multiple row records using mysqli bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I have a code here that works using mysql query.

```
$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES ('$fullname[$i]','$fage[$i]','$frel[$i]','$fcivil[$i]','$fedu[$i]','$foccup[$i]','$finco[$i]','$id')");
```

how to convert this into `mysqli bind_param` here's what I did:
(I have `connection.php` (`mysqli`))

```
$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt ->bind_param("ssssssss",$fullname[$i],$fage[$i],$frel[$i],$fcivil[$i],$fedu[$i],$foccup[$i],$finco[$i],$id);
}
```

but still not getting the data.

Comment: "s" stands for character/string datatypes. in case of integer, use"i". ex:  "sssissi". @kim

Comment: yup I get it. the result im geting string+int. so is it possible to do it in bind_param?

Comment: @SubinThomas no error at all but it doesnt insert the data.

Comment: yes. if your id is integer, use bind_param("sssssssi",..........);

Comment: yup still doesnt work,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91228/discussion-between-subin-thomas-and-kim-de-castro).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you guys looking for solution. here it is:
thanks for those who shared their codes and helping me to give ideas to solved this.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp (fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

for ($i=0; $i<count($fullname); $i++) {
    $fullname1 = $fullname[$i];
    $fage1 = $fage[$i];
    $frel1 = $frel[$i];
    $fcivil1 = $fcivil[$i];
    $fedu1 = $fedu[$i];
    $foccup1 = $foccup[$i];
    $finco1 = $finco[$i];
    $id1 = $id;
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssssi', $fullname1, $fage1, $frel1, $fcivil1, $fedu1, $foccup1, $finco1, $id1);

    $stmt->execute();
}
echo "Done";

$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt ->bind_param("ssssssss",$fullname[$i],$fage[$i],$frel[$i],$fcivil[$i],$fedu[$i],$foccup[$i],$finco[$i],$id);
}
```

you just `bind_param`s and that's all. Statement should be `execute`d. It can be executed several times even with one call for `prepare`:

```
$N = count($fullname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    $stmt ->bind_param("ssssssss",$fullname[$i],$fage[$i],$frel[$i],$fcivil[$i],$fedu[$i],$foccup[$i],$finco[$i],$id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: still not working. no error but it doesnt get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli prepared statements are quite tricky to use, thus, I'd recommend to use PDO instead. With PDO your code would work all right:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute(array($fullname[$i],$fage[$i],$frel[$i],$fcivil[$i],$fedu[$i],$foccup[$i],$finco[$i],$id));
}
```

While for mysqli you have to bind variables first, and then just change subset of variables before execute. And of course you have to call execute() as well.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO famcomp(fullname,fage,frel,fcivil,fedu,foccup,finco,app_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt ->bind_param("ssssssss",$fullname_,$fage_,$frel_,$fcivil_,$fedu_,$foccup_,$finco_,$id);

$N = count($fullname);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    $fullname_ = $fullname[$i];
    // and so on
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note that when using **prepared** statements you have to prepare and bind only once.